# How to know the framebuffer being used?

Tags: linux, gstreamer, framebuffer

While running a graphics application, how to know the `framebuffer` being used? Is it `/dev/fb0` or `/dev/fb1` or something else? Is there any utility for it in `linux`?

I tried with `fbset` utility but it only gives the description of the `framebuffer` I choose to look for.

Comment: Er, `lsof`? The question definitely needs more details.

Comment: Hi Victor.Thanks for your reply.The problem is when i am running a graphics application code written using Open GLES and EGL Apis, a new window pops up in which the graphics is seen.I want to know if it is displayed on any of the framebuffers or not.